# ¿Cómo trabajar correctamente con variables globales en vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

llevo unos días investigando sobre las variables globales en Vue.js ya que me gustaría eliminar el uso de **"imports"** innecesarios para ciertas funciones y datos que voy a necesitar en todo el proyecto. Buscando encontré que el método adecuado para crear globales es el siguiente:

`Vue.prototype.$foobar = foobar`

Pero esto lo que hace es añadir esta variable a todos los componentes, de forma que para usarlo necesitamos escribir:

`this.$foobar`

El caso es que le he encontrado un problema muy grande a esto, por ejemplo al usar **"closures"**. Para los estos casos lo normal es hacer esto:

`var self = this`

Esto provoca que haya dos formas diferentes identificar las globales. **this.$foobar** y **self.$foobar**. Se que suena a una tontería, pero mi proyecto es bastante grande y hay miles de referencias a **"foobar"**, lo que me obligaría a revisar, literalmente, cientos de archivos uno por uno.

He leído que podría usarse la variable window para meter las globales pero no he encontrado referencias a si es una buena o mala práctica o si tiene consecuencias negativas.

En resumen, me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de que las variables sean completamente globales y no dependan del ámbito.

Comment: Trabajar correctamente con variables globales es un oxímoron. Efectivamente, si añades variables al objeto window, van a ser globales. Si eliges este camino, por lo menos es recomendable que crees un espacio de nombres para que los identificadores de variables y funciones no colisionen. Ten en cuenta también que esos datos al tenerlos fuera de una instancia de Vue no van a tener reactividad y si se modifica su valor no se va a ver reflejado el cambio en la IU automáticamente, por lo que te podría interesar tener en las globales las instancias de Vue que a su vez contengan esas variables.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Es justo lo que ya me imaginaba, pero no estaba convencido de que fuera buena idea. Aunque entiendo que tampoco hay más alternativas. Por otro lado, tengo que ver eso que me dices de la reactividad, hasta ahora los imports eran en su mayoría para archivos js y creo que no hemos usado reactividad real, en su lugar pusimos algún watch en el componente donde lo hemos necesitado para añadir la reactividad. Lo cierto es que hay algunas cosas sobre reactividad que aun no domino del todo.